# Calculus, continuity of the derivative at point

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Let $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable in the interval $I$ and let $a\in I$. For any sequences $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $I$ such that $\lim x_n = \lim y_n = a$, $x_n \neq y_n$, we have:

$$\lim \frac{f(y_n) - f(x_n)}{y_n - x_n} = f'(a) \tag{1}$$

Show that $f'$ is continuous at $a$.

The exercise belongs to the section of a book (Elon Lages Lima, Curso de Analise I) where it introduces the Lagrange mean value theorem, so it might be useful here, but I can't figure it out yet.

**Some thoughts**

This condition is stronger than differentiability. For example, the function:
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right),&x\ne 0\\0,&x=0\end{cases}$$
is differentiable everywhere, but $g'$ is not continuous at $0$, hence *not all* pair of sequences $x_n \to 0, y_n \to 0, x_n \neq y_n$ will satisfy (1). Take for example $x_n=\frac1{(2n-\frac12)\pi}$ and $y_n=\frac1{(2n+\frac12)\pi}$, then the limit (1) converges to $-\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: Something's not right here. What are you limits approaching?

Comment: Fix $\epsilon>0$.  Can you write what you want to show, and then show some work towards that goal?  In general, if you start with a sequence $x_n$ that approaches $a$, you will have the luxury of choosing $y_n$ as desired (perhaps to be "sufficiently close" to $x_n$ so some good things happen), just make sure $y_n$ also approaches $a$.  By the way, I think you mean "$f'$ is continuous [at] $a$" rather than "$f'$ is continuous [in] $a$."

Comment: @Michael Fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @Michael : Good observation about $x^2 \sin(1/x)$.  To solve the problem, once you fix a sequence $x_n$ that approaches $a$, you want to show either that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |f'(a)-f'(x_n)| =0$, or  (for a fixed $\epsilon>0$) that $|f'(a)-f'(x_n)|\leq \epsilon$ for all $x_n$ sufficiently close to $a$.  Can you work towards that goal, using approximations for $f'(a)$ and $f'(x_n)$?

Comment: I got a solution on AoPS http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u277018h1271060p6643173 since my post here was closed. Have a look if interested @Michael

Comment: Thanks.  Well, I was hoping you would work it out on your own or at least write a "first sentence" that showed what you wanted to show, and so on.  I would have started with the first sentence I was hinting about, namely...

Comment: ..."Let $\{x_n\}$ be any sequence that converges to $a$.  Fix $\epsilon>0$.  We want to show $|f'(a)-f'(x_n)|\leq \epsilon$ for all sufficiently large $n$.  Let $\{y_n\}$ be any sequence such that $y_n \neq x_n$.  We have by the _triangle inequality_ $$|f'(a) -f'(x_n)| \leq \left|f'(a) - \frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}\right| + \left|\frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n} - f'(x_n)\right|$$

Comment: Sorry about that, I did spend an entire day on the problem, that's why I came here.

Comment: ...So now we have the luxury of choosing, for each $n$, a value $y_n$ sufficiently close to $x_n$ so that two "good things" happen: 1) The second absolute value on the right is at most $\epsilon/2$, 2) $0<|x_n-y_n|\leq 1/n$. [This uses the fact that $\frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}$ is an arbitrarily good approximation of $f'(x_n)$ whenever $y_n$ is sufficiently close to $x_n$.]